# Do methods based on trimmed means require homoscedasticity?

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity, trimmed-mean

I understand (from Wilcox' book [1]) that methods using the trimmed means are robust to distributional assumptions.

Do the methods (e.g. `bwtrim`, from the `R` package WRS) assume that the distribution is the same (although not normal) across all conditions being modelled? In other words, what if the data have heteroscedasticity (more variance in some conditions than others) indicating that distibutions are not the same across conditions?

Example:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(WRS)

data <- data.frame(
A1=rnorm(100),
A2=rnorm(100, 1, 2),
B1=rnorm(100, 5, 5),
B2=rnorm(100,10,10)
)

mdata <- melt(data)
qplot(variable, value, data=mdata)
```

[image: qPlot]

```
# Would it be appropriate to use:
bwtrim(2, 2, data)

$Qa
[1] 149.6878

$Qa.siglevel
     [,1]
[1,]    0

$Qb
[1] 43.91871

$Qb.siglevel
             [,1]
[1,] 8.856752e-09

$Qab
[1] 16.68218

$Qab.siglevel
             [,1]
[1,] 0.0001269782

# or does that assume homoscedasticity?
```

Could anyone recommend an alternative for analyzing this kind of data (i.e. unequal variance)?

[1] Wilcox, R. Modern Statistics for the social and behavioral sciences. CRC Press, 2012.

Comment: "*...recommend an alternative for analyzing this kind of data (i.e. non-parametric and unequal variance)*" -- "data" are not nonparametric. Your methods may be. You need to somehow account for the variance structure in your data.

Comment: OK, thanks, I've edited to focus on unequal variance. As an aside, would you describe methods based on trimmed means as non-parametric? I presume the point of them is that they are robust to distributional assumptions, but they still have parameters that describe the data, i.e. trimmed mean, winzorised variance etc.

Comment: Generally I wouldn't call trimmed means nonparametric (nor distribution-free for that matter).

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation on the bwtrim outside of the book you cite. If you care to explain what you want to do, we could suggest less esoteric, better understood, alternatives

Comment: I want to analyse data that are non-normal and have heteroscedasticity. I chose the method of trimmed means because it's meant to be robust in the case of non-normal data, but then I started to worry about heteroscedasticity. I tried to find some reference to the methods outside of the book, and in doing so I came across some papers from Wilcox and colleagues that I think answer my question! http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1348/000711000159187/pdf  http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~kesel/bjmsp2000.pdf

Comment: @Glen_b whether the methods based on trimmed means are distribution free is a good point, thanks for replying. Wilcox would almost have you believe they are, but he focuses mostly on the mixed-normal or heavy-tailed case.

Comment: @trev under the right sets of assumptions, estimates of location-differences are pretty robust (for particular forms of robustness, at least). But the sort of data I deal with doesn't satisfy the necessary assumptions, and things like variance estimates are more dependent on the distribution. I see in the second paper (1st one is gated, sadly) you link there, Wilcox is using the bootstrap with trimmed means (which for the sort of application there should work okay if sample sizes are not too small), but would work better with a smoother estimator (why not just go to M-estimation, for example?)